# TW Bootstrap Thumbnail Background Colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just wondering how I can change the background colour of a Thumbnail to transparent or different colours in TW Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways to do that , the first one is to customize bootstrap from the official websites **http://getbootstrap.com/customize/**

Change value of `@thumbnail-bg`

Seconde solution is to override bootstrap classes like @Billy Moat said

Answer (score 2):

Normal practice when using Bootstrap is to load the bootstrap.css file then straight after that load another custom stylesheet of your own e.g.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In this new stylesheet you can modify any of the Bootstrap default styles to suit your own design requirements e.g.

```
.thumbnail {
    background: #000;
}
```